# insert rows to table with PRIMARY KEY from different tables without PRIMARY KEY sql server

Tags: sql-server

I hope to explain very well my problem

I have a new table with a Primary Key.

How to insert the table from different tables?
my problem is the one table without Primary Key and I don't know how to select from table one row and insert to the new table.

Example -

new table 1
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jLAg.png)

- AssetId is Primary key

table 2
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwzvW.png)

- I need to insert one row to table 1

table 3 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRHGj.png)

my script -

```
insert AssetBusStops (AssetId,StopCode,StopId,Description,ZoneId)
select  Assets.Id,stops_ppp.stop_code,stops_ppp.stop_id,stops_ppp.stop_desc,stops_ppp.zone_id from Assets inner join stops_ppp 
on Assets.AssetCode = stops_ppp.stop_code
```

> Exception -
>
> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 11
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_AssetBusStops'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AssetBusStops'. The duplicate key value is (2763).
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions. Also, what is the primary key of the `dbo.AssetBusStops` table? And is this question really related to MySQL or is it actually something about "SQL server" (looks like that)?

Comment: @Progman thank you for help... my question to SQL server and primary key to assetId in table AssetBusStops

Comment: Is it okay to have only unique `AssetId` values in your `AssetBusStops` table or do you expect to have multiple rows with the same `AssetId` value? Please [edit] your question to include the output of the `SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... ON ....` part to your query. Also check if there are entries with the same `Assets.Id` value, specially for the value `2763`.

Answer (score 1):

The value `20001` of the column `AssetCode` of the table `Assets` matches 3 rows from the table `stops_ppp` and these 3 rows in the result joined query have the same value `2763` in the column `id`.
 
So your query tries to insert 3 rows, not just 1 and this would create duplicates in the primary key, which is not allowed.
You should apply a filter in the results of the query, something like:

```
insert AssetBusStops (AssetId,StopCode,StopId,Description,ZoneId)
select top 1 ASsets.Id, 
  stops_ppp.stop_code, stops_ppp.stop_id, stops_ppp.stop_desc, stops_ppp.zone_id 
from Assets inner join stops_ppp 
on Assets.AssetCode = stops_ppp.stop_code 
order by stops_ppp.stop_code
```

This (for your sample data) returns only 1 row (an arbitrary ow as you requested in the comments) and can be safely inserted.

Comment: Thank you may friend....
if I want to select top(1)  row from stop_ppp and insert to table assetbusstops,
how to do this?

Comment: TOP 1 in what order?

Comment: All 3 rows have the same stop_code so this will pick an arbitrary row. Is this that you want?

Comment: No there is no need for CROSS APPLY. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

A) If you don't have FK to table AssetBusStops :

1. Change PK Column to IDENTITY(1,1)
2. Remove PK value from Insert script

B) If you have FK to table AssetBusStops :
try to use Not Exists or Merge